# Rest webservice generate client stubs

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I have a simple REST webservice and using Jersey client to consume it. I would like to to know how can I generate a stub client if I have a WADL, similar to wsdl2java do we have anything for wadl?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [wadl2java](https://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html) that *generates a java client based on the provided WADL that makes use of the Jersey 1.x and JAX-RS 2.0 client API*.

Comment: Where I can download the jar for jersey for wadl2java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Accurest to create stubs of your HTTP JSON based services. Also you can use Stub Runner to automatically download stubs in your tests: https://github.com/Codearte/accurest